# Add header in text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The purpose in the below is to add header in a single big file and to generate a pages divided by the header.

The header need to be added every 7 lines with the option to increment the number in the Page. Means every time one header is been added the number in the page will increase.

Header

```
----------------------------------------------------
 Code       10       20       30       40     Page 1
----------------------------------------------------
```

Input file

```
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
```

Output file

```
 Code       10       20       30       40     Page 1
----------------------------------------------------
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 2
----------------------------------------------------
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 3
----------------------------------------------------
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 4
----------------------------------------------------
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40      Page 5
----------------------------------------------------
 2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
 2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
 2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
 2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
 2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
 2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: looks good, what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, no code yet done..:).. Please help me.

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to improve yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, at some point you're going to have to crack open a book and start learning this stuff for yourself. I recommend Advanced Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Ed, tks for the advise,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option that doesn't require any system commands.

```
$ cat a.awk
BEGIN {
    hdr1 = "----------------------------------------------------\n"
    hdr2 = "Code       10       20       30       40     Page %d\n"
    hdr3 = "----------------------------------------------------\n"
    hdr = hdr1 hdr2 hdr3
}

NR % 7 == 1 { printf hdr, ++page }1
```

```
$ awk -f a.awk file
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 1
----------------------------------------------------
2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 2
----------------------------------------------------
2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 3
----------------------------------------------------
2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 4
----------------------------------------------------
2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
----------------------------------------------------
Code       10       20       30       40     Page 5
----------------------------------------------------
2917        2        0        0        0  =      2
2916        0        0        0        5  =      5
2915        2        0        3        0  =      5
2914        2        2        1        0  =      5
2912        0        2        0        0  =      2
2911        0        2        0        0  =      2
2910        3        0        0        0  =      3
```

Comment: Jas, can I ask a question please. Is it possible to get as variable the value of column 3 for each time the header is added. Example in the fist time header es insert in row 1 then row 7, then row 14 and so on. So the purpose is to grep the value in column 3 in that lines and add to the header after page , can be Code = value. Tks

Comment: At the time the header is printed, the value of column 3 for rows 1,8,15,... will be in `$3`.

Comment: jas, exactly, but want to grep this value and keep it in one variable to add it in the header.  after Page (value) will apper Code (value) . Can you please add it in your code.

Comment: You've asked and gotten answers to 24 _awk_ questions --- and I mean this with all kindness --- can you at least try :-)  You only need to understand the `printf` statement (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html)

Comment: Jas, I will do tks.. My doubt was only to catch the value in row for column 3 at the time.the header will be inserted . anyway I will try. Appreciate your comments and I will read about printf.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    line = 0;
    page = 1;
    # delete old file called out.txt
    cmd = "rm -f out.txt"
    system(cmd);
    close(cmd);
}

{
    cmd = "cat header.txt | sed 's/Page 1/Page "page"/' >> \"out.txt\""  # pay attention to header.txt and to the sed command
    if (line == 0) {
        system(cmd);
        close(cmd);
    }

    print $0 >> "out.txt"
    line++;
    if (line == 7) {
        line = 0;
        page++;
    }
}
```

`out.txt` is where the output will be saved

`sed` command replaces `Page 1` from the header with the correct number and print out on `out.txt` the right number of the page with the header

You should execute the script like this:

```
./script.awk file
```

Where `file` is the input file that you need to parse and edit

`script.awk` is the script that you have to make executable with `chmod +x script.awk`.

PS:

The `rm` command in `BEGIN` block is done because in the main block we append lines to `out.txt` and if a `out.txt` already exist, that, is a problem because the append operation doesn't delete the old content of the file and we will append new lines to it.

Comment: ninosanta, it works fine, Is the the possibility to add the option to increment the number in the Page, for each time there new header was added, like in the desired output.

Comment: @OXXO sorry, I have not seen that detail. Now I edited the post and added a `sed` command and a variable called `page`. Together do that part of the question

Comment: ninosanta, sorry i got the msg " runaway string constant"   cat header.txt, perhaps it is because the variable page need to be assigned -v to avoid to use the "page" and only use page?.

Comment: @OXXO page is a local variable of the script initialized into the `BEGIN` block so it shouldn't be a problem. Instead, did you call the text file containing the header `header.txt`? Because the script suppose you did that.
Your error message is too generic and  not formatted. `AWK` suggest even the line of the error.

Comment: minosanta, yes the file header.txt is there.. Before we add the sed option it works, that is reason I thought the msg comes because "" in the variable.

Comment: @OXXO if you look carefully, you can see that `page` is not inside a couple of `"` but is in the middle of this string `"cat header.txt | sed 's/Page 1/Page "` and this one `"/' >> \"out.txt\""`. Most of your attention must be focused on the start of the second string `"/'` you can see `"` that starts the string followed by `/` that is the end of the string that `sed` use to replace the other one  and in the end there's `'` that end the `sed` command.
`sed` commands, in that case, follow this semantic `sed 's/stringWeHaveToReplace/stringThatReplaceTheString/'`

Comment: minosanta, yes it works now,, appreciate your indications.

Comment: minosanta, yes it works now,, appreciate your indications.